# Need Help Parsing Text Between HTML Tags

Tags: c#

Ok, the problem it's that i have string with HTML. I need to find an specific format like this:

`<span class="fieldText">some text</span>`

of that HTML, I need to extract `some text` and save it into a list. How can accomplish my goal.

note that the text can appear like this

```
<p>
    Central: 
<span class="fieldText">Central_Local</span><br>Area Resolutoria:  
<span class="fieldText">Area_Resolutoria</span><br>VPI:  
<span class="fieldText">VIP</span><br>Ciudad: <span class="fieldText">Ciudad</span>   <br>Estado:  <span class="fieldText">Estado</span><br>Region  <span class="fieldText">Region</span>    
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try regex: `@"<span .*?>(.*?)</span>"`
If you combine it with captures you can get the whole list with `@"^(.*?<span .*?>(.*?)</span>.*?)+$"`.

But the truth is you shouldn't use regex for XML or HTML - there is a plenty of parsers out there, as others have already mentioned.

```
            string s = @"
<p>
    Central: 
<span class=""fieldText"">Central_Local</span><br>Area Resolutoria:  
<span class=""fieldText"">Area_Resolutoria</span><br>VPI:  
<span class=""fieldText"">VIP</span><br>Ciudad: <span class=""fieldText"">Ciudad</span>   <br>Estado:  <span class=""fieldText"">Estado</span><br>Region  <span class=""fieldText"">Region</span>    
</p>";

            Match m = Regex.Match(s, @"^(.*?<span .*?>(.*?)</span>.*?)+$", RegexOptions.Singleline);

            foreach (var capture in m.Groups[2].Captures)
                Console.WriteLine(capture);
```

Comment: hi, and thanks for asking the regular expression works well but only bring's me the first match, i tried to change the regular expression adding `\b` to get all the line but it doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

I don't like using regular expression for stuff like this.

I've written a free [HTML tag parser](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/parsing-html-tags-in-c) that you could either use as is, modify to fit your needs, or just use as a guide to how you might approach this on your own.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

For small stuff like this I prefer using regular expressions. Not sure what the C# syntax is, but the expression would look something like this:

```
|<span class="fieldText">(.+)</span>|
```

Jonathan Wood's suggestion for using an HTML tag parser is a good idea too, especially if you'll be doing a lot of parsing.

Answer (score 0):

Regex has been shown to be a bad solution for parsing HTML. The [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) is exactly what you need for this task.